# Scheduling multiple jobs with dynamic parameter using Quartz 1.6.2 (simple trigger) + Spring 3.0

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am trying to create a sample scheduler program using quartz simple trigger. My    objective is run a single method with different parameters passed dynamically by user (considered as new Job)and schedule it for user defined time which is also received dynamically.

```
eg: 
public void printMe (String name, int Age, Date dob) {
        system.out.println("Name:"+name+" Age:"+age+" DOB:"+dob);
}
```

How to schedule and execute this method based on dynamically received parameters and   start date and time using quartz 1.6.2. I am new to quartz scheduler, I have no idea how to do this. Do anyone help me with the sample programs you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example to use quartz job via simple trigger

Simple Trigger 1 minutes with 1 second delay for every run to execute:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    JobDetail job = new JobDetail();
    job.setName("dummyJobName");
    job.setJobClass(HelloJob.class);
    //configure the scheduler time
    SimpleTrigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger();
    trigger.setStartTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000));
    trigger.setRepeatCount(SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY);
    trigger.setRepeatInterval(100000);// set time run again is 1 minutes

    //schedule it
    Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
    scheduler.start();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

}
```

You create class for execute class job

```
    import org.quartz.Job;
    import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
    import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

    public class HelloJob implements Job
    {
     public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
     throws JobExecutionException {

     printmMe("YourName",20,"12/15/2013");  

      }

          public void printMe (String name, int Age, Date dob) {
              system.out.println("Name:"+name+" Age:"+age+" DOB:"+dob);
          } 
     }
```

Above, that's program use quartz schedule to execute job HellloClass

Comment: Thank you Hao Luong. Your example is really helpful to me, I have added the param values in JobDataMap to pass to execute method and done with what I want. Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: Oh... I'm very glad It's been helpful for you